# How to show more details in typeahead Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, bootstrap-typeahead

I use directory `typeahead` from Bootstrap in Angular.
How I can to display more results in HTML template? Now I get only `name`:

```
typeahead="job as job.name for job in getJobPlace($viewValue) | filter:{name:$viewValue}"
```

I need something like as:
job as job.name, photo as job.photo...

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use simple string concatenation

```
typeahead="job as job.name +' '+ job.id for job in getJobPlace($viewValue) | filter:{name:$viewValue}"
```

Comment: Thanks, can I prepare data inside `typeahead` like as: `job as Prepare(job.name)` ? Or in template `{{prepareImgJob(match.model.photo)}}` ?

Comment: @Hamed it would be `typeahead="job as prepare(job) for job in getJobPlace($viewValue) | filter:{name:$viewValue}` then implement your own logic in controller `prepare` method

Comment: I mean `{{prepareImgJob(match.model.photo)}}` where `prepareImgJob` function from controller

Comment: no it should be without `{{}}` interpolation that means you need to only use `prepareImgJob(match.model.photo)` on typeahead

Comment: @Hamed do you want anything else?